# Как получить разность двух таблиц, используя JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Помогите решить задачу на SQL, над которой я ломаю голову уже несколько дней.

Даны две таблицы с одинаковой структурой:
key1, key2, value1, value2, value3. Key1 и key2 очевидно ключи. В таблицах могут быть отличия как в ключах, так и значениях, значения могут содерждать NULL.

Необходимо получить третью таблицу, которая будет содержать в себе различающиеся строки из заданных таблиц, при этом нужно указать из какой таблицы берется каждая из строк.

Итого должна получиться таблица source, key1, key2, value1, value2, value3. Также бонусом можно добавить столбец, который будет указывать причину ошибки: 0 - у таблиц различается атрибутивный состав записей, 1 - запись есть только в одной из таблиц.

СУБД Postgres. UNION использовать нежелательно, EXCEPT также, нужны JOINы.

Comment: Что значит `UNION` использовать нежелательно? По какой причине?

Comment: Т.к Union ресурсозатратный при большом количестве столбцов. А если потребуется масштабирование, то запрос станет неэффективным. Ну и в целом, такое условие

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT t1.*, 1 AS source
FROM t1
NATURAL LEFT JOIN t2
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.*, 2
FROM t2
NATURAL LEFT JOIN t1
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```

`tN.id` - это первичный ключ таблицы либо любое NOT NULL поле. В структуре из вопроса может использоваться любое поле из выражения композитного первичного ключа, например, `key1`.

> Union ресурсозатратный при большом количестве столбцов. А если потребуется масштабирование, то запрос станет неэффективным.

В свете того, что потребуется объединение двух таблиц по всем полям, на "ресурсозатратность" UNION уже можно смело наплевать. И запрос изначально по жизни неэффективен.

Comment: К сожалению, запрос отвечает ошибкой синтаксиса. ERROR: ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "NATURAL")
LINE 4: LEFT NATURAL JOIN Prototype t2
             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 41

Comment: @VladMarchenko Postgres хочет сначала NATURAL, а потом всё остальное... могли бы и сами посмотреть. Поправил.

Comment: спасибо. Пока только учусь, поэтому такие вопросы.  Также есть еще один вопрос. В результат дважды попадает строка, которая одинакова в обеих таблицах, у нее одинаковы ключи, одинаковы value, но одно из value null. Как это можно поправить?

Comment: @VladMarchenko Никак. NULL не равен вообще никакому значению. Даже другому NULL. И вообще неясно, что тут поправлять - значения-то разные, как и заказывали...

Comment: Наверное, я не совсем понятно выразился. Значения для данной одинаковы в обеих таблицах. Что в первой таблице value3 = null, что во второй таблице value3=null. А так как значения во всех ячейках строки в  t1 совпадают со  значениями в t2, то в вывод попадать они не должны.

Comment: @VladMarchenko Я, по-моему, вполне ясно выразился - NULL **НЕ РАВНО** NULL. Сравнение NULL = NULL (равно как сравнение NULL с любым другим значением) даёт в качестве результата NULL, который интерпретируется как FALSE. Если же Вы желаете, чтобы два NULL были равны - пишите кастомное выражение сравнения (`WHERE t1.column=t2.column OR (t1.column IS NULL AND t2.column IS NULL)`). Но тогда про NATURAL забудьте, пишите сравнения для каждого поля отдельно.

Comment: И даже IS DISTINCT FROM не поможет...

Comment: Спасибо, во-первых вы открыли мне глаза. А во-вторых - выяснилось, что это была задачка с подвохом, т.к в предложенном  в условии результате, отсутствовали эти строки  с null